# Collection mongodb with 290M w/ 6 $group don't return any result

Tags: mongodb, collections, spring-data-mongodb

I've this mongodb query:

```
{ "$match" : { "dtTransacao" : "2021-09-03"}}, 
{ "$group" : 
    { "_id" : { "dtTransacao" : "$dtTransacao", "cdBandeira" : "$cdBandeira", "cdEmissor" : "$cdEmissor", "cdProduto": "$cdProduto", "nuBinCartao": "$nuBinCartao"}, "sumValueTransaction" : { "$sum" : 1}}}])
```

My collection have almost 21gb and 290M registers...
this collection (clTransacoesAutorizacao) have 14 columns and when I tried ever returns:

**via mongo compass**

MongoNetworkError: connection 14 to 10.10.109.46:27017 closed

**via my application**

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

When i try a select w/ two columns in $group, my query returns values.

**a detail:** I've two sites(locale) in different province, and My query with 6 items in $group works in one of them.

Comment: Was it the server that closed the connection, or a network problem in between?

Comment: When i try a select w/ two columns in $group, my query returns value. 

I tried using mongo compass and and via my application.

via compass returns:
MongoNetworkError: connection 14 to 10.10.109.46:27017 closed

via my application returns:
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

Answer (score 0):

My mongodb had 1 CPU core, it increases to 4 cores and it starts working.